# Display temp from weather API

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, api

I need to identify and fix the error.
What am I missing here and why? The temperature does not display.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/EWX/155,90/forecast/hourly'
  }).done(function(res) {
    var temp = res.properties.periods[0].temperature;
  });
  document.getelementbyid('temperature').innerHTML = temp
</script>
<p>
  The temperature is <span id="temperature"></span>F.
</p>
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: getelementbyid might not work careful to capital letters : correct form is document.getElementById('temprature')

Comment: I need the temperature to show here. <p>
                                The temperature is <span id="temperature"></span>F.
                            </p>

Comment: What gives you `console.log(temp)` ?

Comment: You can move `document.getelementbyid('temperature').innerHTML = temp` inside done callback.

Comment: Got it! Thanks Hassan Imam!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is two-fold. The first is that there is a scoping issue trying to bring "temp" outside of when it will be ready. That is only set within the `.done()` call.

The second issue found is that the `document.getelementbyid` should be `document.getElementById()` as per the specification https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/EWX/155,90/forecast/hourly'
  }).done(function(res) {
      document.getElementById('temperature').innerHTML = res.properties.periods[0].temperature;
  });
});
</script>
<p>
    The temperature is <span id="temperature"></span>F.
</p>
```